# Effects of dropping "AUDIT_WRITE", "KILL", "SETFCAP" and "SETPCAP" capabilities while running docker

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, container, capabilities

I'm exploring Docker container capabilities and permissions and I'm curious about the implications of dropping the "AUDIT_WRITE", "KILL", "SETFCAP" and "SETPCAP" capabilities.

Can anyone provide a clear explanation of what these capabilities allow within a Docker container by default? What specific actions or operations might be restricted or impacted within the container after dropping them?
I'd very thankful if you tell me a scenario that after dropping these capabilities, it will change compared with the existence of them.